# In Postgresql how to speed up substring queries

Tags: sql, performance, postgresql

I have a simple logs table with about 500,000 rows, table structure is

```
 TABLE logs
(
  id serial NOT NULL,
  username character varying(32),
  user_id integer,
  description text NOT NULL,
  "time" timestamp with time zone DEFAULT now(),
  referrer character varying(128),
  "type" character varying(25)
)
```

The most common operation in terms of querying this table for contents of the **description** column. Typical query is...

```
SELECT username , time , description FROM logs WHERE description ~* 'some text'  ORDER by time DESC
```

This takes anywhere from 8 ~ 20 seconds, to bring back results. Is there any other method to optimize the table or query that would produce faster results. I'm on 8.2 Portgresql .

Answer (score 3):

First of all, you should upgrade to 8.4 to get all new performance benefits. 8.4 has integrated tsearch for [full text searching](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/textsearch.html). If you can't upgrade, install [Tsearch2](http://www.sai.msu.su/~megera/postgres/gist/tsearch/V2/) from contrib.

For further optimization, I'd create an index for `time` and use it to limit results. E.g.

```
SELECT username , time , description FROM logs WHERE 
    to_tsvector('english', description) @@ to_tsquery('english', 'some text')
    AND time > current_timestamp - INTERVAL '1 day'
    ORDER by time DESC
```

See the linked documentation for further information. You'll need to create an index for `to_tsvector` or the full text search is quite useless.

**Edit**: If your table contains millions of tuples of data, consider recreating the whole table using [partitioning](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.2/static/ddl-partitioning.html) available in 8.2. For raw speed improvement, switch to SSD disks. See [this article](http://it-blog.5amsolutions.com/2010/08/performance-of-postgresql-ssd-vs.html) for demonstration of speed increase.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a column (boolean) which gets set on insert and update via. a trigger, this would then be searchable, but the search terms would always be the same.

Have you considered using [Full-text search?](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/static/textsearch.html)  You'll have to install the FTS module manually in your version of postgres.